# Single foreach loop statement on dynamically named arrays with a common prefix?

Tags: php, foreach, dynamic-allocation

```
$size_of_groups = "4";
// for the purpose of the question, assume $seeded_teams size is currently 32, it's array that returns data from a function i have created, 
//however the size can change
// depending on user input

// creates dynamically named arrays (i realize this is a poor way of doing 
//things, but, for my purposes it is fine
$ft = "true"; 
for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($seeded_teams) / $size_of_groups + 1; $i++) {
    if ($ft == "true") {
        ${"group{$i}"} = array($seeded_teams[0], $seeded_teams[sizeof($seeded_teams) / 2 - 1], 
        $seeded_teams[sizeof($seeded_teams) / 2], $seeded_teams[sizeof($seeded_teams) - 1]);
        $ft = "false";
    } else {
        ${"group{$i}"} = array($seeded_teams[-1 + $i], $seeded_teams[sizeof($seeded_teams) / 2 - $i], 
        $seeded_teams[sizeof($seeded_teams) / 2 - 1 + $i], $seeded_teams[sizeof($seeded_teams) - $i]);
    }
}
```

I am creating arrays with dynamic names in my script. All arrays created this way are appended with a number.
For example: $group1, $group2, $group3, $group4, $group5, $group6, $group7, $group8

If I know (and my script understands) exactly how many arrays there are (and as a result, will know all of the appensions), I was wondering if there was anyway to execute a single statement that understands to go through all 8 of those arrays without having to call 8 seperate loops.

I imagine that it would probably be much better to just rewrite this portion of the code to use multidimensional arrays but I wrote a few other functions using this information quite a while ago when I was far less experienced, and hadn't realized the scope of the project. Note, this project is for personal purposes only.

To give a better example, is it possible to do something like this?

```
for($i=0;$i < $number_of_groups + 1; i++) {
    foreach ($"{group{$i}"} as $value) {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [`variable variables`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_groups + 1; i++) {
    $var = 'group' . $i;
    foreach ($$var as $value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```